# How to make git repository browsable but not clonable?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I would like to potentially show some of my works to future prospective employers. But I do not necessarily want them to just clone and take my work and develop from it. My work is currently just a few HTML & CSS projects, I don't want them to just clone it and develop from it. I would like them to just be able to see the code and possibly also my commit histories (via a browser on gitlab.com website).

I know that they could inspect and view source or even save the page while viewing the website, but I guess everyone could do that to any website. But the work is considered a little bit more demanding than just cloning a project and fork another project from it.

If I make my GitLab repository public, everyone can clone and fork from it.

Is it possible that I can make it public (browsable via Gitlab website), but disable the `git://` protocol and also other methods to anonymously clone from it?

Answer (score 7):

> **No**, there is no way to prevent people from cloning or downloading your repository if they have access to it.

If you are worried about others using your code without your express permission, I would suggest adding a license. License protects you legally and gives you control over your codebase.

You can [visit this](https://choosealicense.com/) site to help to decide which license to use.

**Alternate Solution**

If you just want to show your codebase and don't care/want open-source-iness. You can try following,

- ZIP or RAR your repository
- Put it on google drive
- Get a shareable link
- Click advanced - Check to prevent people from downloading or sharing the file

Anyone with the link can see what's inside the directories and the structure, but can't open or view the content of the files. They will not be able to download as well.

Comment: Well using a license does not prevent anyone from breaking the license. I don't want people from using my codebase and developing from it (specifically cloning and forking it), I don't mind if they inspect my page or view source on it. See the distinction here, they are bit different. Maybe there is no solution to this now, but who knows.. BTW I dont find a license that match my needs yet, from https://choosealicense.com/appendix/ , the closest is maybe EUPL, but I want to disable commercial use and also patents..

Comment: If I decide to release my codebase, I might only want ppl to improve on it, but not selling the from derivative of my work and release it the same way. Google drive might not work, there is no commit history (therefore the timeline of my projects). I think maybe the closest way right now is to have people who want to view it sign up gitlab and grant him/her permission to read the repo, but that is kinda a hassle to be honest lol.. idk if those are realistic now..

Comment: @K4ll-of-D00ty, If they have read access to it, they will be able to download the codebase and use it. The license will help you at a certain level like no one can use for commercial purposes. If you are so much worried about source code, keep it private and create some kind of explanatory video or blog to explain about the codebase.

Comment: lol, I am not that worried about my source code, probably not as much as like how you framed it. I already said, I don't mind them viewing it (see the 1st comment). Maybe there is no solution to my need right now, that's fine. (Maybe I hope they will hv that feature in future idk, I don't even know if that's possible from the protocol & infrastructure standpoint.. idk).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Can-I-give-read-only-access-to-a-private-repo-from-a-developer/m-p/2062#M640) on Github

> @FirstPrinciples-AI wrote: I don't want to give fork/clone/download rights.

It's worth noting here that cloning a repository is a central operation in the collaboration model that GitHub provides. For example, the read-only access that we currently offer to GitHub Organizations still allows users to both clone and fork the repositories that they have permission to read:

https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/

With all of that in mind, I believe that it's unlikely that we'll change our permission model to disable the ability to clone a repository that someone has read access to; even if we do allow for read only access to private repositories owned by user accounts in the future.